# Assigning different shipping cost based on time of day

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

Can I assign different shipping cost based on time in Prestashop?

For example, From 11am - 5pm products should sell at X shipping cost and on X+10 shipping cost when time is 5pm,- 10pm etc.

Comment: One possible solution that comes to my mind is I could update the shipping cost field in my store db when the server time meets a specific criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to create new shipping module for this specific carrier, here you can read how to do that:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+carrier+module

In `getOrderShippingCost` method you should insert your code where you'll check current time and modify shipping costs.

Of course those are basis, there are plenty of options here, you can modify method `getShippingPackageCost` in `Cart.php`, you can modify cost in database using some dynamic hook after order creation etc.